# "Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint" error

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have 3 main entities : Category , SubCategory , Products:

```
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        Photos = new List<Photo>();
        Comments = new List<Comment>();
        Colors = new List<ProductColor>();
        Attributes = new List<ProductAttributes>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string BrandName { get; set; }
    public string SellerName { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public bool OnSale { get; set; }
    public int SalePercantage { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    public int UnitsInStock { get; set; }

    public string MainImageUrl 
    { 
        get 
        {
            return Photos.Count > 0 ? Photos[0].PhotoPath : "https://dummyimage.com/600x600/e0d0e0/ffffff.png";
        }
    }

    public decimal ShownPrice 
    {
        get 
        {
            if (OnSale) 
            {
                return SalePrice; 
            }
            else 
            {  
                return Price; 
            }
        } 
    }

    public decimal SalePrice 
    {
        get 
        {
            return (decimal)((decimal)Price - ((decimal)Price * ((decimal)SalePercantage / (decimal)100)));
        }
    }

    public bool IsNewBrand 
    {
        get 
        {
            return DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3) <= DateAdded;
        } 
    }

    public int SubCategoryId { get; set; }
    public SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }
    public List<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public List<ProductColor> Colors { get; set; }
    public List<ProductAttributes> Attributes { get; set; }

    public List<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; }
    public List<ProductProductSize> ProductSizes { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public List<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; }
    public List<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
}

public class SubCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

In my `DbContext`, I define my relationships:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ProductCategory>().HasKey(p => new { p.CategoryId, p.ProductId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<ProductCategory>().HasOne(p => p.Product).WithMany(d => d.ProductCategories).HasForeignKey(p => p.ProductId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ProductCategory>().HasOne(p => p.Category).WithMany(d => d.ProductCategories).HasForeignKey(p => p.CategoryId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<SubCategory>().HasOne(p => p.Category).WithMany(d => d.SubCategories).HasForeignKey(p => p.CategoryId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasOne(d => d.SubCategory).WithMany(p => p.Products).HasForeignKey(d => d.SubCategoryId);
}
```

When I'm trying to migrate my database from PowerShell, I'm getting this error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_ProductCategory_Products_ProductId' on table 'ProductCategory' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

I couldn't recognize the issue here, what am I doing wrong?

Shouldn't I have the `HasOne.WithMany` code with my `ProductCategory` entity or something like that?

I tried almost everything and could not find the solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)` in your `ProductCategory` *Fluent API* configuration as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProductCategory>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Product)
            .WithMany(d => d.ProductCategories)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.ProductId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict); // <-- Here it is


modelBuilder.Entity<ProductCategory>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Category)
            .WithMany(d => d.ProductCategories)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.CategoryId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict); // <-- Here it is
```

Now generate the migration again and update the database.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it was  " WillCascadeOnDelete() " but changed as " OnDelete() " I did not know that , thanks again.